# Customize link when I hover on a div

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this code:

```
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <div class="comments-qty">
       <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="link-to-post"><a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hover the div "buttons-wrapper", I want to change the color of `fa-chevron-right`. I used this:

```
.buttons-wrapper:hover + .fa-chevron-right{
    background-color:green;
    color:white !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @AleshaOleg That question uses jQuery to show/hide elements; it's not a duplicate, though one surely exists elsewhere.

Comment: @TylerH ok, ok - sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: @AleshaOleg that question didn't help me , in fact i used the response of that question and didn't work , this is why i posted an other question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
.buttons-wrapper:hover + .fa-chevron-right{
background-color:green;
color:white !important;
}
```

should be this

```
.buttons-wrapper:hover .fa-chevron-right{
background-color:green;
color:white !important;
}
```

Since `.fa-chevron-right` is not a sibling of `.buttons-wrapper`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this as `+` is used for next sibling selector to select child element use `.buttons-wrapper:hover  .fa-chevron-right{`

```css
.buttons-wrapper:hover  .fa-chevron-right{
background-color:green;
color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <div class="comments-qty">
       <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="link-to-post"><a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-right">adsadsd</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the plus symbol.

```
.buttons-wrapper:hover .fa-chevron-right{
background-color:green;
color:white !important;

}
```